# Deleting extra spaces with html

Tags: html, spaces

Ok so I made a random webpage for fun and I'm just about done with this page I made. There's only one thing though. There are extra spaces in the page. Here is my code:

file:///C:/Users/ezeki/Desktop/HomeFlix%20Website%20HTML/homeflix.html

Comment: Just need that HTML code so we can help you

Comment: Copy the code inside your HTML file and edit your question to include it. We cannot access your HTML from your local filepath